# Finding html elements in jquery

Tags: html, jquery-selectors

I am supposed to find a class and apply a logic for that.
My code structure is as follows.

```
<div class="class">

  <form>

    <ul>
      <li>xxx</li><li>xxx</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>xxx</li><li>xxx</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="ul_class">

      <li>
        <input ....><a ...><span ..></span>
        <a href="#" title="View History" class="hstry">
        <span class="hide">&nbsp;</span></a>
      </li>

      <li>xxx</li>

     </ul>

   </form>
```

How to find the class `hstry` inside the `ul` with the class named `ul_class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a normal CSS selector to find nested classes like the following:

```
$( 'ul.ul_class .hstry' )
```

Note the whitespace between both classes. Without it, it would match an element having both classes, instead of an element with class `hstry` which is below some `<ul>` element with class `ul_class`.

Comment: Say for ex. I have 3 ul's with same class, how can I locate my fist ul and access its .hstry class

Comment: @Abdul In that case you would just append `.first()` to only target the first matching element. See http://api.jquery.com/first/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content, try

> var hstry = $('body').find('.hstry').html();

Then you can operate with this variable any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery: 
`$("ul.ul_class").find(".hstr");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.ul_class .hstry').html(); //for html content
$('ul.ul_class .hstry').text(); //for text data
```